# sbt - copy SOME libraryDependencies to output lib folder

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

Using sbt, I'd like to copy **some** dependency jars to a `lib` output folder. If possible, I'd like to use the `%provided%` keyword, like I can with sbt-assembly.

So given a `build.sbt` somewhat similar to the following, how do create a task that copies the `ark-tweet-nlp` but NOt the `spark-core` dependencies to `target/scala-%ver%/lib` ?

`retrieveManaged := true` simply copies everything, which is not what I want.

```
...
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "edu.cmu.cs" % "ark-tweet-nlp" % "0.3.2"

retrieveManaged := true
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a task like this.

#### `build.sbt`

```
val retrieveNotProvided = taskKey[Unit]("Copies non provided and non internal dependencies")

def isInternalOrProvided(conf: String) = conf.contains("-internal") || conf == "provided"

retrieveNotProvided := {
  val toCopy = new collection.mutable.HashSet[(File, File)]
  val pattern = retrievePattern.value
  val output = managedDirectory.value
  update.value.retrieve { (conf, mid, art, cached) =>
    import org.apache.ivy.core.IvyPatternHelper
    val fileName = IvyPatternHelper.substitute(
      pattern, mid.organization, mid.name, mid.revision, art.name, art.`type`, art.extension, conf
    )
    if (!isInternalOrProvided(conf)) toCopy += (cached -> output / fileName)
    cached
  }
  IO.copy(toCopy)
}
```

You'll have to remove `retrieveManaged := true` from your `build.sbt`, because otherwise sbt will trigger the original retrieve function.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! For my purpose (`spark-shell --jars`), I needed a comma-separated list of project jar(s) and dependency jars, which can be produced with : `find target/scala-2.10 lib_managed/jars -name *.jar | paste -d, -s`